# Ubuntu boot stuck in "emergency mode"

Tags: boot

During boot, my Ubuntu 22 is stuck saying "You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or exit to boot into default mode. Press Enter for maintenance. Press Ctrl+D to continue".

However, I cannot make sense of journalctl output and Ctrl+D brings back the same output.
I used the program "boot-repair" using a live Ubuntu USB. It says boot repaired, but it doesn't fix the problem. The log from boot-repair is here - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/77T3tVfnyj/plain/.

I also updated my nvidia drivers before this happened. However, I also purged all nvidia drivers in root mode now, which didn't fix anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am new to linux and ubuntu.

Comment: Did you make any changes to /etc/fstab? I notice your /home is mounted by dev instead of by UUID.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: No, I haven't made changes to fstab recently. My home is in a different hard drive than the OS. My only recent change was updating the nvidia driver, which does not appear to be the problem.

Comment: Consider changing the fstab to mount your home by UUID. The definition of which hard drive is "sda" or "sdb" can change at boot time, and if you mount your home by dev, you can get into this situation.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: unfortunately, changing to UUID in the fstab did not fix the boot. I still am stuck with the same message during boot.

Comment: That was the only thing suspicious I saw in the output. I am sorry it didn't help.

Comment: Thanks for your help though. I wish the messages were more useful. I may need to reinstall ubuntu.